# Перелив заливки CSS

Tags: css

Как в CSS организовать плавный перелив бэкгрунда, стартующего с одного цвета и заканчивающегося с другого?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Градиент? [Генератор градиента](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте gradient в background. [Здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/css3-na-primerakh/lineinyi-gradient) для начинающих хорошо описано, да впрочем и не только для начинающих.